# If Else If In a Sql Server Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this function I am trying to create. When I parse it, it works fine, but to actually create the function in the database it says my column names are invalid. That is not true, I spelled them correctly. Here is the code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally] (@SchoolId nvarchar(50))
RETURNS int

AS 

BEGIN 

DECLARE @Final nvarchar
IF EXISTS (

    SELECT 
        question, 
        yes_ans, 
        no_ans, 
        na_ans, 
        blank_ans 
    FROM dbo.qrc_maintally 
    WHERE school_id = @SchoolId 

)

    IF yes_ans > no_ans AND yes_ans > na_ans 
    BEGIN
        SET @Final = 'Yes'
    END

    ELSE IF no_ans > yes_ans AND no_ans > na_ans 
    BEGIN
        SET @Final = 'No'
    END

    ELSE IF na_ans > yes_ans AND na_ans > no_ans 
    BEGIN
        SET @Final = 'N/A'
    END

RETURN @Final

END
```

Comment: Is `school_id` the PK on that table? i.e. can there ever be more than one matching row?

Comment: @G_M refresh, I did that a few minutes ago.

Comment: There is no PK in this table but yes it could be used as one. And the values of yes_ans, no_ans, etc are integers so I'm trying to compare each row per schoolId and which ever has the greatest value, then output a final value.

Comment: @Salim - Well if more than 1 row matches which row should be used in the calculation? Also why is your function declared as `RETURNS int` when it actually returns `varchar`? Also you need to declare a length for all your varchar variables. e.g. `DECLARE  @Final VARCHAR(3)`

Comment: If more than one row matches then another review will be done on our site and that reviewer will be a case breaker.

Comment: @salim - So what should your function return if more than one row matches and they have different results?

Comment: @Martin- Basically they are not worried about that and it should return whatever the greatest value is. If answers have matching values someone else will take care of that part by submitting another row

Answer (score 9):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally] (@SchoolId nvarchar(50))
    RETURNS nvarchar(3)
AS BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Final nvarchar(3)
    SELECT @Final = CASE 
        WHEN yes_ans > no_ans  AND yes_ans > na_ans THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN no_ans  > yes_ans AND no_ans  > na_ans THEN 'No'
        WHEN na_ans  > yes_ans AND na_ans  > no_ans THEN 'N/A' END
    FROM dbo.qrc_maintally
    WHERE school_id = @SchoolId

Return @Final
End
```

As you can see, this simplifies the code a lot.  It also makes other errors in your code more obvious: you're returning an nvarchar, but declared the function to return an int (corrected in the code above).

Comment: `DECLARE @Final nvarchar` needs a length or will get truncated at 1 character.

Comment: @Martin - copied that from the original question.  I can't put a length there until the OP tells us what it needs to be.

Comment: @Joel `varchar(3)` should work fine with the string literals in the code.

Comment: @Joel Coehoom: Martin's right. But there's another problem too. You are returning an `nvarchar` while the function is declared to return `int`.

Comment: @Martin - okay, you got me, but in my defense I don't think he needs to declare a return variable at all (updated my answer to reflect this).

Comment: @Andriy - again, I pulled that from the question. That's the OP's mistake.

Comment: Sorry guys I just caught that regarding the return int part, its now returning an nvarchar. I will try the various examples here and see which works for me.

Comment: @Joel - Sorry I wasn't trying to catch you out. The edited version does still need a return type of some description. (Maybe table if you were planning on converting it to an inline TVF?)

Comment: Arg, I was thinking stored procedure.

Comment: I could use it as a stored procedure, just sucks my coworker decided to create the tables like this and didn't really provide a simpler way of figuring out this stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to create local variables for those columns, assign them during the select and use them for your conditional tests.

```
declare @yes_ans int,
        @no_ans int,
        @na_ans int

SELECT @yes_ans = yes_ans, @no_ans = no_ans, @na_ans = na_ans 
    from dbo.qrc_maintally 
    where school_id = @SchoolId

If @yes_ans > @no_ans and @yes_ans > @na_ans 
begin
Set @Final = 'Yes'
end
-- etc.
```

Comment: On the right track, but we can do even better by assigning to @Final directly from a CASE statement

Comment: @Joel - Assuming of course that only one row can match the condition.

Comment: @Martin - you need that for the variables here, too

Comment: The comment was really about the degree of "right trackness" not specifically anything to do with the CASE statement. The OP says multiple rows can be returned for a `schoolid` but I'm still somewhat baffled by their explanation so +1.

Comment: Specifically each schoolId has about 18 rows since there are 18 questions its confusing explaining without visually seeing it.

Comment: Is there anyway to execute this and test it before I place it on the webpage? It seemed to have executed and completed fine.

Comment: @salim @Martin @Joe - The code still doesn't return the `greatest` value - it has 3 double-inequality tests. See my answer

Answer (score 3):

No one seems to have picked that if (yes=no)>na or (no=na)>yes or (na=yes)>no, you get NULL as the result. Don't believe this is what you are after.

Here's also a more condensed form of the function, which works **even if** any of yes, no or na_ans is NULL.

```
USE [***]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnActionSq]    Script Date: 02/17/2011 10:21:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally] (@SchoolId nvarchar(50))
RETURNS nvarchar(3)
AS 
BEGIN
return (select (
       select top 1 Result from
       (select 'Yes' Result, yes_ans union all
        select 'No', no_ans union all
        select 'N/A', na_ans) [ ]
        order by yes_ans desc, Result desc)
       from dbo.qrc_maintally
       where school_id = @SchoolId)
End
```

Comment: Thanks Richard I could try this as well although the webform does not allow nulls anyway

Comment: This works as a select query but not in code behind as a function, doesn't spit anything back out

Comment: A variable still needs to be declared for receiving the result of the query and for being pushed out as the result of the function.

Comment: I hadn't and now I have. Obviously I was wrong, sorry. There probably was a similar situation in a different context where it was mandatory to use a variable (or at least it was impossible to pull the result of a subquery directly), and I managed to confuse it with `RETURN`. Can't remember what it was, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
If yes_ans > no_ans and yes_ans > na_ans
```

You're using column names in a statement (outside of a query).  If you want variables, you must declare and assign them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off with a CASE statement, which works a lot more like IF/ELSEIF

```
DECLARE @this int, @value varchar(10)
SET @this = 200
SET @value = (
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN @this between 5 and 10 THEN 'foo'
    WHEN @this between 10 and 15 THEN 'bar'
    WHEN @this < 0 THEN 'barfoo'
    ELSE 'foofoo'
    END
)
```

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines:

If yes_ans > no_ans and yes_ans > na_ans

and similar. To what do "yes_ans" etc. refer? You're not using these in the context of a query; the "if exists" condition doesn't extend to the column names you're using inside.

Consider assigning those values to variables you can then use for your conditional flow below. Thus,

```
if exists (some record)
begin
   set @var = column, @var2 = column2, ...

   if (@var1 > @var2)
      -- do something
```

end

The return type is also mismatched with the declaration. It would help a lot if you indented, used ANSI-standard punctuation (terminate statements with semicolons), and left out superfluous begin/end - you don't need these for single-statement lines executed as the result of a test.